# Missing attributes on User

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Looking to retrieve the pager attribute for user on Microsoft graph. Doesn't seem to be in v1.0 or beta.

When I run

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/
```

I get most of the attributes I need however I also need to return the pager attribute.

when i do `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me?$select=displayname,pager` it doesnt work

I had a look at the meta data and see pager under PhoneType but unsure how to retrieve it.

From `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata`:

```xml
<EnumType Name="phoneType">
    <Member Name="home" Value="0" />
    <Member Name="business" Value="1" />
    <Member Name="mobile" Value="2" />
    <Member Name="other" Value="3" />
    <Member Name="assistant" Value="4" />
    <Member Name="homeFax" Value="5" />
    <Member Name="businessFax" Value="6" />
    <Member Name="otherFax" Value="7" />
    <Member Name="pager" Value="8" />
    <Member Name="radio" Value="9" />
</EnumType>
```

Any help on this would be fantastic. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear, The `/beta` version actually returns *all* of the user's attributes. The `/v1.0` version includes a default `$select`, but the `/beta` version applies no selection or filter criteria of any kind.

More importantly, `phoneType` enumeration is not used by the `user` entity. It is only used by the `person` and `contact` entities.

The `phoneType` enum is only referenced by the `microsoft.graph.phone` type (which comes from Exchange, not AAD):

```xml
<ComplexType Name="phone">
    <Property Name="type" Type="microsoft.graph.phoneType"/>
    <Property Name="number" Type="Edm.String"/>
</ComplexType>
```

In turn, the type `microsoft.graph.phone` is only applied to two resources: `person` and `contact` (i.e. Outlook Contacts):

```xml
<EntityType Name="person" BaseType="microsoft.graph.entity">
    <!-- snipp -->
    <Property Name="emailAddresses" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.rankedEmailAddress)"/>
    <Property Name="phones" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.phone)"/>
    <Property Name="postalAddresses" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.location)"/>
    <!-- snipp -->
</EntityType>
<EntityType Name="contact" BaseType="microsoft.graph.outlookItem" OpenType="true">
    <!-- snipp -->
    <Property Name="manager" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <Property Name="phones" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.phone)"/>
    <Property Name="postalAddresses" Type="Collection(microsoft.graph.physicalAddress)"/>
    <Property Name="spouseName" Type="Edm.String"/>
    <!-- snipp -->
</EntityType>
```

The `user` entity does not contain a `pager` property (nor most of the others listen in the `phoneType` enum).

Comment: Thanks so much for coming back to me