# Microsoft Graph API get Contact info

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have configured an AD in Azure environment and has granted permissions `User.Read` and `User.Read.All` to get user details via graph api. I want to read AD user contact info but api send only below details as mentioned in the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1).

```
 {
  "businessPhones": [
       "businessPhones-value"
   ],
   "displayName": "displayName-value",
   "givenName": "givenName-value",
   "jobTitle": "jobTitle-value",
   "mail": "mail-value",
   "mobilePhone": "mobilePhone-value",
   "officeLocation": "officeLocation-value",
   "preferredLanguage": "preferredLanguage-value",
   "surname": "surname-value",
   "userPrincipalName": "userPrincipalName-value",
   "id": "id-value"
}
```

Azure AD Contact info
[image]

Any permissions or any configurations I am missing here to get the rest of the details?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Missing attributes on User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53636198/missing-attributes-on-user)

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the properties you want ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters)).

Like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<upn or objectId>?$select=streetAddress,state,country,officeLocation,city,postalCode,mobilePhone,businessPhones
```